# Callback with parameters

Tags: c, callback

Im trying to figure out how to use callbacks with parameters in C. The following isnt working. What is the best way to archieve it? (passing arguments for the callback function)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void caller(int (*cc)(int a)) {
    cc(a);
}

int blub(int a) {
    printf("%i", a); 
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    caller(blub(5));
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: I would `typedef int (*callback_t)(int);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are doing the call before passing the function, not passing the callback function itself. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void caller(int (*cc)(int ),int a) {
    cc(a);
}

int blub(int a) {
    printf("%i", a); 
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    caller(blub, 1000);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`caller` expects a function pointer and you're giving it an integer.  You need just `caller(blub)`.

Also `int (*cc)(int a)` is invalid syntax.

```
void caller(int (*cc)(int), int a) {
    cc(a);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    caller(blub, 5);
    return 1;
}
```

Is probably the closest thing to your code which could work.